# Stuck on many to many to many data call for an uni Assignment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have an assessment I am not having an easy time of. I keep getting stuck on very small stuff. Im a 3d artist learning to code. So the part I am currently stuck on (small part of quite a large assignment) is I have a home page that lists restaurants like a food portal similar to like uber eats. Clicking on those restaurants is meant to load up a specific menu to the restaurant. But I can't seem to get this working. The database has 10 menu items per restaurant ID and 5 Restaurants in total. I am using sqlite3 as the database with seeder data'. 
Ive had many errors but the latest is "Call to undefined relationship [menus] on model [App\Menu]."
Any help is appreciated, Ive already wasted so much time on seeder issues and now getting stuck on this part feels so trivial compared to the rest of the assignment :( 
Hopefully I have provided enough information. Thanks!

Routes page:

```
    Auth::routes();

    Route::resource('/', 'HomeController');
    #Route::resource('show', 'MenuController');
    Route::resource('main', 'HomeController');
    Route::get('show/{id}', 'MenuController@show')->name("show");
```

Main blade

```
    <p>
    @foreach($restaurants as $restaurant)
            <a href="{{ route('show', $restaurant->id) }}">
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ $restaurant->name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
            </a>

    @endforeach
    </p>
```

Show.blade

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('title')
        Home Page
    @endsection

    @section('content')

        @foreach($menus->menu as $menu)
            <td>
                {{ $menu->id }}
            </td>
        @endforeach
```

users.php

```
    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->hasMany(Menu::class,'App\Restaurant');
    }
```

Restaurant.php - Model

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
```

Menu.php - Model

```
    public function user(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'menus_id');
    }
```

Home Controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $restaurants = Restaurant::all();
        return view('home', compact('restaurants'));
        //return view('home')->with('restaurants', $restaurants);
    }
```

Menu Controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $menus = Menu::all();
        return View::make('show', compact('menus'));
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        $menus = Menu::find($id)
        ->with('menus')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();
        return view('menu.show', compact('menus'));
    }
```

Comment: Your `Menu` model does not have a `menu` relationship.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying in the show function? The eloquent methods put together there to get $menus are a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Wish I could, just got back from class..and even more confused about what I'm trying to do now..:(